# Java Object Method Not Accessible

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

In the following code, the file runs fine if I take the password.setEchoCar(*char*) method call out.  Why can I not call it when the object is created right above it?

There shoudlnt be a scope problem and I checked the javadoc for the method, it seems to be the correct method for specifying a non-default password character.

Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Authenticator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
    password.setEchoChar('%');
    JTextArea comments = new JTextArea(4, 15);
    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    public Authenticator () {
        super("Account Information");
        setSize(300, 220);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JLabel usernameLabel= new JLabel("Username: ");
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        JLabel commentsLabel = new JLabel("Comments: ");
        comments.setLineWrap(true);
        comments.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        pane.add(usernameLabel);
        pane.add(username);
        pane.add(passwordLabel);
        pane.add(password);
        pane.add(commentsLabel);
        pane.add(comments);
        pane.add(ok);
        pane.add(cancel);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Authenticator.setLookAndFeel();
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're executing code outside of an executable context

Comment: You can't execute code in the field decleration area of the source code, it needs to be in a constructor, method or static initialisation block.

Comment: Put another way: you've put code to perform an action where only variable declarations are allowed.

Comment: @dave No plain talk, techno babble only! ;)

Comment: `JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
    password.setEchoChar('%');` is this possible ?? should move `password.setEchoChar('%');` inside the constructor .

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to execute code out side of an executable context (within the variable decleration area)...

```
public class Authenticator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
    password.setEchoChar('%');
    //...

    public Authenticator () {
        //...
```

Move `password.setEchoChar('%');` to the constructor

```
public class Authenticator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
    //...

    public Authenticator () {
        super("Account Information");
        password.setEchoChar('%');
        //...
```

Comment: ok, that actually makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.  So, is it "not in an executable context" because this is the main class, and is not automatically an object?  I mean, if the main method was in another class, would the decleration area be in contect then, or must it always be in a method such as the constructor?

Comment: It's not an "executable context" because that's how Java works.  You can't place "functional" code out side of the context of constructor or method (and a couple of other places), but not where you have it right now, regardless of weather it has a `main` method or not.

Comment: You should note, @Terryl, that variable declarations and initializations (e.g., `JTextField username = new JTextField(15);`) are not considered, in this context, functional code. You can create new objects, but you can only use them inside of methods (like the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

```
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
{
  password.setEchoChar('%');
}
```

You can do that in an [initializer block](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/should-i-use-initializer-blocks-in-java), but unless you have initialization code that is common to a number of constructors, it's considered good style to do it in the constructor.

Comment: Do you mean that it can be in the deceleration area so long as its in a block; as in Java sees any block as a functional code area?  I thought the blocks were just for defining scope; scope of a variable, scope of a method/ class, etc. @Mike

Comment: `{ ... }` blocks inside a method, constructor, or initializer behave as you describe (see [Ch 14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)).   When directly inside a class, `{ ... }` is an [*initializer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) which functions as described in the doc linked from my answer, and `static { ... }` is a *static initializer* which runs at class load time.